# Get all values from one-to-many relationship in one row

Tags: mysql, left-join, concatenation, one-to-many

I have a one-to-many relationship in my database. 
[image]

I want to fetch all cities with all the cinemas appended in one row as CSV. I have tried:

```
SELECT city.*,CONCAT(cinema_name)
FROM city
LEFT JOIN cinema
ON cinema.city_id=city.city_id
GROUP BY city.city_id
```

But this only returns first cinema.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use GROUP_CONCAT instead of CONCAT

```
SELECT
  city.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(cinema_name) AS `Cinemas`
FROM city
  LEFT JOIN cinema
    ON cinema.city_id = city.city_id
GROUP BY city.city_id
```

Comment: use inner join instead of left join

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT ct.city_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cinema_name) 
FROM cinema c, city ct
WHERE c.city_id = ct.city_id
Group BY c.city_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

For current versions of Mysql Tested on **V5.7** if you want that data as a json object you can try this.

```
SELECT
  city.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
JSON_OBJECT(
'cinema_name', cinema_name
)) AS `Cinemas`
FROM city
  LEFT JOIN cinema
    ON cinema.city_id = city.city_id
GROUP BY city.city_id
```